# Selecting a data value from pandas dataframe based on row and column to append to list

Tags: python, list, pandas, append, dataframe

I have a PandasData Frame that is 26 columns and 100 rows. I want to extract a particular value from column 25 (which is called Unnamed: 24) row 50 and throw it into a list. Is there any way to do this? My columns are called Unnamed: 0, Unnamed: 1, ..., Unnamed: 25; and the rows are just going 0  to 99:

```
     Unnamed 0:   .....     Unnamed: 24     Unnamed: 25
  0
  1
  .
  .
  50                              50
  .
  .
  99
```

and

```
Numbers = []
```

I want to append this value 50 to Numbers which is from column 24 row 50.

My data frame is x = xls.parse('excelfile1.xls'), I am parsing a dataframe from an excel spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-integer) for this:

```
Numbers = []
value =  df1.iloc[24,50]
Numbers.append(value)
```

Or as a more general example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,5), data=[range(5*i,5*i+5) for i in range(0,5)])
```

`df`:

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
2  10  11  12  13  14
3  15  16  17  18  19
4  20  21  22  23  24
```

and print `df.iloc[2,2]` returning `12`

Comment: Is it possible to use iloc to do something like the following: what if I wanted to select every value on row 2? Could I do df1.iloc[(0,1),(0,2), ... (0,26)]? Thanks for the great answer. It worked for me

Comment: If you want every value from row 2 you can just do `df.iloc[2]` or `df.iloc[2].values` respectively. PS: if the answer worked for you make sure to upvote ;)

Comment: I need 15 reputation to upvote :( but I gave you a green checkmark. Thanks!

Comment: Ah i remember. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

For selecting a single value from a DataFrame or Series, [`at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#fast-scalar-value-getting-and-setting) (label based scalar indexing) and [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#fast-scalar-value-getting-and-setting) (index based scalar indexing) are generally the fastest.

```
numbers = []
numbers.append(df.iat(50, 24))
```

Lets say you had three pairs of numbers representing row and column index values where you want to lookup a value from your DataFrame.  You could efficiently accomplish this goal as follows:

```
pairs = [(10, 20), (20, 25), (30, 30)]
[numbers.append(df.iat(row, col)) for row, col in pairs]
```